# Could electric dipoles within hadrons provide an alternate explanation for strong force?

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, quarks, dipole, strong-force

We all know that hadrons such as proton and neutrons are made up of quarks and not all of the quarks have the same charge.  This would suggest that they have a positive and negative side.  In the case of the neutron the negative and positive sides would be about equal, but in a proton the negative side is probably I guess about one quarter of the size of the positive side.
We all know from nuclear physics that the nucleus is held together by strong force which only seems to exist in a very tiny range.  Is it possible that the hadrons are simply rotating so their attracting poles face each-other and perhaps this only happens at a very small distance because at far distances the electric field of the odd-charged quark is canceled out by the others?

Comment: Are you implying that this possibility wasn't thought of when the quark model was established? Or are you asking what aspects of this mechanism make it negligible compared to the (actual) nuclear strong force?

Comment: Have you tried to make a back-of-the-envelope calculation to see if the EM dipole effect is relevant to the nucleus?

Comment: As a gentle reminder to others -- please do not post answers in the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it could not.  The strong interaction has a different set of symmetries than the electric dipole moment.

Specifically, the strong interaction is invariant under [inversion of space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)), under [reversal of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry), and under [conjugation of charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-symmetry).  These symmetries are known from observing which types of nuclear transitions are allowed or forbidden in strongly-interacting systems.

A [theorem about angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem) says that any permanent dipole moment must be aligned or anti-aligned with a particle's spin.  (A corollary is that spinless particles, which are non-orientable, can't have a permanent dipole moment.)  An electric dipole would change sign under inversion of space, which would be equivalent to having the two charges switch places, and would also change sign under conjugation of charge for the same reason; however, reversing the direction of time does not change the direction of an electric dipole.  By contrast, the direction of angular momentum does *not* change sign under parity or charge conjugation, but *does* change sign under time reversal.  So a particle with a permanent electric dipole moment would transform under parity inversion and charge conjugation in a different way than a particle which participates in the strong interaction.

In the jargon, we say that a permanent electric dipole moment would be "$CP$-violating."  The combined transformation $CP$ (that is, charge conjugation and parity inversion) transforms matter particles to antimatter and vice-versa.  Since the universe contains more matter than antimatter, we *know* that there are $CP$-violating interactions which we haven't yet observed, and those $CP$-violating interactions predict that protons, neutrons, and electrons should have some small permanent electric dipole moments.  There are several experiments searching vigorously for these observables.  But those electric dipole moments aren't the cause of the strong force.